# I am trying to connect angular pod with Springboot app pod | Failing With Approaches

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using `AWS` cloud

My k8s chart as follows
[image]

I have added load balancer with default 80 port mapping to my angular pod, and so is I am able to access my website.

But UI -> service calls which are from my Angular client are failing, because I cant call ALB URL again, since ALB restricted to route single instance.

My Angular App using NGINX capability.

How should I can make calls to my `backend services` from client ? Do I need to add `Ingress Controller` ?

This is my nginf configuration

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name _;
        
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        
    }
}
```

I tried by adding ALB URL, Cluster IP URL multi things still no luck yet !
[image]

Ingress apply
[image]

And my Ingress Controller is

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # UPDATE THIS LINE ABOVE
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
          # UPDATE THIS LINE ABOVE
            backend:
              serviceName: ng-modern-app-service
              servicePort: 31000
          - path: /gkonnect/*
          # UPDATE THIS LINE ABOVE
            backend:
              serviceName: gikonnect-service
              servicePort: 30163
```

After Ingress rule applied
[image]

`AWS` Load Balance Configuration
[image]

Comment: You screenshot does not provide enough information, but from what I see, I believe you have a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue.

Comment: Sorry @ErvinSzilagyi for inconvenience, I have  to made blurr some part of screens. I do have CORS enabled configuration at my Spring Controllers already.

Comment: I just tried by applying `ingress-controller , updating latest screen shots without blurr